# How to correct "The injection target must not be declared static." warning

Tags: java, websphere, ejb-3.0

I am getting the warning

"The IssuePermitProcessManager.ecmManagerLocal injection target must not be declared static."

on my `WebSphere 9` server console.  I believe the code causing the issue is:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class IssuePermitProcessManager implements IssuePermitProcessManagerRemote, IssuePermitProcessManagerLocal {

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction userTransaction;

    @EJB
    protected static EcmManagerLocal ecmManagerLocal = null;
    protected final static String EcmManagerLocal_JNDI = "ejblocal:gov.mo.dnr.ecwis.sessions.ecm.EcmManagerLocal";
```

I am not clear on what the injection target is.  Do I just remove the `static` from the `protected static EcmManagerLocal ecmManagerLocal = null;` declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `ecmManagerLocal` is an injection target (it is annotated with `@EJB` to inject an ejb) that is declared static. Replace the line of code,

```
    @EJB
    protected static EcmManagerLocal ecmManagerLocal = null;
```

with

```
    @EJB
    protected EcmManagerLocal ecmManagerLocal;
```